# Which one is better sentence? "...a class for becoming/to become a tour guide"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, adjuncts, for

- I took a class **for becoming** a tour guide.
- I took a class **to become** a tour guide.

Which one is more natural of saying?

Comment: "I took a class to become a tour guide" sounds better to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...**to** **become** a tour guide. (NOT *for* *becoming* a tour guide)

We don't use '*for*' before a *verb* to talk about *purpose*. Instead, we use **to** + infinitive.

She went to Canada **to** attend the conference. He is studying everyday **to** improve his English. I am going to New York **to** visit my grandmother.

[[ We can use **for** before a **noun** to talk about a **purpose**.

I went to Paris **for** an interview. He went to the pub **for** a drink. He is studying hard **for** the exam.

We can use  before a verb to talk about the **purpose of a thing**. (the reason **why we use it**)

We use an altimeter  measur height above sea level. That stuff is (used)  clean leather. The garden shears are used  clip the hedge. He wears these old trousers  paint.]]